# How to fix 'Method's type signature is not PInvoke compatible' error in C#

Tags: c#, c++, struct

All I need to know is how to return a struct from a PInvoke in C++ that has the following struct. For the moment I can deal with it being blank and I just want to know how to return the struct under the conditions set in the code.

I've tried with with the entire struct that I need to return and isolated each part of struct to know which part is giving me the issue (which will be made apparent in the code provided).

I've tried the same method by wanting to return a few integers within the struct which works fine. (Tried to make this bold using ***, ___)

```
//.header file
typedef struct { //Defintion of my struct in C++

    TCHAR  msg[256];

}testTCHAR;

//.cpp file
extern "C" {
    __declspec(dllexport) testTCHAR* (_stdcall TestChar(testTCHAR* AR))
    {
        AR->msg;
        return AR;
    }
}
```

In my C# I Call the .dll as:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public delegate void testChar(testTCHAR AR);

[DllImport("C:\\Users\\jch\\source\\repos\\FlatPanelSensor\\x64\\Debug\\VADAV_AcqS.dll", EntryPoint = "TestCallBackChar", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public unsafe static extern testTCHAR TestCallBackChar([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)] testChar call);

//Struct
public struct testTCHAR
        {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
            public string rMsg; //I assume the error should be fixed here 
                                  but to what exactly I don't know.
        }

//Defining the callback
testChar tChar =
                (test) =>
                {
                    //As far as I'm aware this part can be left blank
                      as I followed a tutorial online
                };

testTCHAR returned = TestCallBackChar(tChar); //This is where the error 
                                                happens
```

I just need to return the struct, preferably with a value attached to it.

The error I get is 'Method's type signature is not PInvoke compatible.' Which is in the title, but I'm covering all basis.

If you need anymore information about this please ask away and I should be able to provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `testTCHAR` type contains managed references, you cannot use a pointer as a part of signature (which you didn't), but also it does not make sense to pass it by value (this is why the runtime produces the error you see).

You need to change your signatures so that it's apparent that you want to pass a pointer into the native method:

```
public delegate void testChar(IntPtr data);
public unsafe static extern IntPtr TestCallBackChar([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)] testChar call);
```

When calling you need to explicitly marshal structures to the managed equivalent (and vice versa):

```
testChar tChar =
    (inputPtr) =>
    {
        testTCHAR input = (testTCHAR)Marshal.PtrToStructure(inputPtr, typeof(testTCHAR));
    };

IntPtr returnedPtr = TestCallBackChar(tChar);
testTCHAR returned = (testTCHAR)Marshal.PtrToStructure(returnedPtr, typeof(testTCHAR));
```

Additionally, I guess there is a mismatch between C++ and C# signature and method name.

Comment: It works, thank you @Daniel Balas much appreciated.